# Libreoffice document recovery automatization

Tags: libreoffice

I am wondering if there is a way I can launch libreoffice so it does document recovery or exits. I want this so when my computer boots up and I log in I am immediately prompted with document recovery. I want libreoffice to exit if there are no documents to recover. Is there a command line argument that will achieve this I can add to my gnome session?

Answer (score 2):

> I want libreoffice to exit if there are no documents to recover.

Isn't that superfluous ?
Here's one possible solution. It will only start LibreOffice (**LO**) if there's actually any document to recover. Otherwise nothing will happen.
**LO** saves the information needed to restore all open documents in case of a crash in so called *"Temporary files"*. The default location (in linux) is `/tmp` and **LO** saves the data in some directories under `/tmp`.

- Change that location to a dedicated directory for temporary files, preferable under `$HOME`:

Create new dir:

```sh
mkdir -p ~/.cache/lo
```

Start **LO** and go to **Tools - Options - LibreOffice - Paths**
Select **Temporary files** and click **Edit** (or double click the entry)
Select (navigate to) the newly created directory:

```
/home/YOURUSERNAME/.cache/lo
```

save, close **LO**. So from now on **LO** will place the temporary files (with names like `lu2s2clv.tmp`, `lu2s2clx.tmp`, `lu2s2cly.tmp` etc) in a directory with a similar name, e.g. `lu2s2ckt.tmp` under `~/.cache/lo`. It's only a matter of checking if there's anything to recover and fire up **LO**.

- Create a script:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

sleep 2
[ -e ~/.cache/lo/*.tmp ] && libreoffice
```

save it somewhere in your `$PATH` e.g. `/usr/local/bin/odrecover`, make it executable.
Then fire up `gnome-session-properties` and add `/usr/local/bin/odrecover` to your start-up programs. Next time you log in, if there's any document to recover **LO** will automatically prompt you with document recovery.

---

Note: `sleep 2` in the above script is needed on my system so that **LO** starts after `gpasted` (clipboard manager daemon) otherwise, for some unknown reason, `gpasted` goes crazy.